# Is the change of outline-offset, on pressing any keyboard key on anchor tag, the expected behaviour?

Tags: html, css

In the following demo, click and hold the mousedown on the anchor tag, then drag your cursor away, while holding mousedown, and then finally let go of the click. You will see a red dotted outline around the anchor tag. Now if you press shift key the outline will get offset by a few pixels.

```css
a:focus {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Click+hold, then release, then press shift key</a>
```

The behaviour doesn't occur on pressing `ctrl` or `fn` keys etc, but does happen for most keys. This behaviour seems to be cross browser compatible, which leads me to ponder:

- Is it a bug in the implementation of HTML by the browsers?
- Or, is it the expected behaviour suggested by w3.org for some user experience issues?

Comment: Firefox doesn't have that behaviour. Edge and Chrome have, i think all * blink engine* based have same bug.

Answer (score 3):

By clicking an element and then pressing `Shift`, as you said, or in [some other situations determined via heuristics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible), you are triggering both `:focus` and `:focus-visible` states. Browser will then apply its default styles for these states.

The result you are reporting can be reproducted in Chrome because of its [default user agent stylesheet](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/third_party/blink/renderer/core/html/resources/html.css#1306), but not in Firefox, for example. You can test this on your own by opening DevTools and forcing the states of the `a` element.

The following example reproduces Blink (Chrome's rendering engine) default styles so it can be seen in other browsers:

```css
a:focus {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}

a:any-link:focus-visible {
  outline-offset: 1px;
}

/* for non-Blink WebKit browsers */
a:-webkit-any-link:focus-visible {
  outline-offset: 1px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Example link</a>

<!-- To see the result described in the question for sure, 
     please force :focus and :focus-visible states using DevTools -->
```

Comment: Right on spot. Webkit browsers apply `a:-webkit-any-link:focus-visible {
    outline-offset: 1px;
}`. This is not observed in Firefox. I wonder how does pressing a key on keyboard induces the focus-visible state, though.

Comment: If you could point to a resource that confirms this as being the case in specific on webkit browsers it would be better. However, this is still a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @4127157 Great call. I linked Chrome UA stylesheet source code and made a correction to my answer, because I noticed the aforementioned default style is from Blink and not WebKit.

Answer (score 0):

By default there is an animation set to this if outline-offset is not defined. You can see animation set on outline-width [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-width#formal_definition) in animation type in Formal Definition. A function is set on animation type which helps in animation. When animated, values of the  data type are interpolated as real, floating-point numbers. The interpolation happens on the calculated value. The speed of the interpolation is determined by the [timing function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/easing-function) associated with the animation causing the outline-offset increase from 0px to 1px.

References:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/easing-function
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#interpolation https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/outline-width.

You can check and verify these thoroughly on these links.

Comment: Well the thing is that its not a bug or anything its just a default behaviour if the offset is not given.

Comment: Default behaviour of outline-offset

Comment: You could be right, because all browsers seem to have this behaviour -- all browsers are unlikely to have the same bug. But, my question is what does w3.org say about it? Is it the expected behaviour inline with w3c recommendation or did browsers have to do this as a by product of some other css feature?

Comment: I have updated the answer according to your requirement. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: The links you have given do not say _there's an animation **applied** to outline-offset_. User agents do not apply css3 animation by the themselves. _"animation type a length"_ means the property _is_ animatable and gets animated _smoothly_ in pixels(not percent).

Comment: @user31782 kindly read that again that property animatable is the one causing this effect it works with a length which is a timeframe that completes when the focus starts and is lost and the function converts the value of outline-offset from 0px to 1px. I didn't mention percent thou.

Comment: How do you know it animates from `0px` to `1px` and not to `2px` or `3px` for example? And what are the values of `animation-delay` and `animation-duration`? How do you know the animation happens on `focus` event? Why doesn't it happen on `hover` event? Listen, this whole thing has nothing to do with css3 animations. Please read my previous comment again. Or ask anyone else in stackoverflow chat.

Comment: My friend it is written in the easing function that it changes it from 0px to 1px. Kindly read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/easing-function

Comment: Formal definition
Initial value medium
Applies to all elements
Inherited no
Computed value an absolute length; if the keyword none is specified, the computed value is 0
Animation type a length(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#interpolation). which have easing function written on it. All this data is available on https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/outline-width. These are not some random links these are given on the w3's website you can verify that by going o these links.

Comment: If you believe your answer is correct, answer the points I [raised in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68865356/is-the-change-of-outline-offset-on-pressing-any-keyboard-key-on-anchor-tag-the/68918681?noredirect=1#comment121836621_68918681).

Comment: It animates from 0px to 1px because of the easing function. This easing function is applied on the animation type of outline and you can verify that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-width#formal_definition). When you open the url embedded in the 'length' it will take you to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#interpolation where it is stated that 'The speed of the interpolation is determined by the timing function(also known as easing function) associated with the animation.'

Comment: An easing function can animate from any value to any values, e.g. `10px` to `17px`. You still haven't answered the points I raised in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68865356/is-the-change-of-outline-offset-on-pressing-any-keyboard-key-on-anchor-tag-the/68918681?noredirect=1#comment121836621_68918681)

Comment: The easing functions in the cubic-bezier subset of easing functions are often called "smooth" easing functions, because they can be used to smooth down the start and end of the interpolation. They correlate an input ratio to an output ratio, both expressed as <number>s. For these values, 0.0 represents the initial state, and 1.0 represents the final state. It will always end at 1.0 which means that it can not animate to more than 1px. Check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/easing-function

Comment: You comment is technically incorrect. _It will always end at 1.0 which means that it can not animate to more than 1px._ is technically wrong. [In this example](https://jsfiddle.net/ozxpL7a8/1/) I have animated outline-offset from `2px` to `7px`. Another one: https://codepen.io/cobblucas/pen/gpjVKb

Comment: My friend, by default it will show this behaviour of 0px to 1px, however we can manipulate it according to our need.

Comment: If you don't set any offset then it will go from 0px to 1px

Comment: Thats not technically correct. Default won't do anything. css animations/transitions are not applied by themselves; they need to be explicitly defined..